# Typescript 1.5 exporting/importing classes

Tags: typescript

It might be a misunderstanding from my part. In Typescript 1.4 we use to export import classes, but when I updated my code to typescript 1.5 the behavior changed.

Here is how it worked in TS 1.4

`LanguageForm.ts`

```
import AbstractForm = require('../components/AbstractForm');

class LanguageForm extends AbstractForm {
    buildPanel(){

    }
}
export = LanguageForm;
```

From my understanding in TS 1.5 the syntaxt needs to be modify to :

```
import AbstractForm from '../components/AbstractForm';
export default class LanguageForm extends AbstractForm {
    buildPanel(){

    }
}
```

Whith TS1.4 I could simply do a call on `new` in order for it to work in a dynamic setting :

```
require(["LanguageForm"], (Form) => {
    new Form()
});
```

now in TS 1.5 I need to do :

```
require(["LanguageForm"], (Form) => {
    new Form.default()
});
```

**My question**
In all the example I found the documentation was exporting/importing modules. Is that the way to export/import classes? Can I get rid of the `.default`?

Comment: [Documentation for imports](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In all the example I found the documentation was exporting/importing modules. Is that the way to export/import classes

Don't use `export =`. Instead export:

```
export class LanguageForm extends AbstractForm {
    buildPanel(){

    }
}
```

And import:

```
import {LanguageForm} from '../components/LanguageForm';
```

Comment: Do you put the import statement inside the class or outside?